# Why does my web API not return JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

I made a very simple web API controller to reproduce an error in a more complex one, this controller only has the minimum amount of code to reproduce the error.

The controller code is as follows

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace NWCloudBorgEmployee.Controllers
{

    public class WmsInfo
    {
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemQty { get; set; }
    }

    public class WmsInformation
    {
        public List<WmsInfo> WmsInfos { get; set; }
    }

    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/WmsInfo")]
    public class WmsInfoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/WmsInfo
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "You need to send in a barcode as ID to get the correct return data" };
        }

        // GET: api/WmsInfo/5
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            var test = new WmsInformation();
            test.WmsInfos = new List<WmsInfo>
            {
                new WmsInfo { StoreName = "SE001", ItemName = "Item1" , ItemQty = "10"},
                new WmsInfo { StoreName = "SE002", ItemName = "Item2" , ItemQty = "115"}
            };

            return test.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the API I get a string as below instead of the JSON data

```
"NWCloudBorgEmployee.Controllers.WmsInformation"
```

Why is it not returning the JSON?

Comment: Is `test.ToString()` default? If it the the default shouldn't you override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're calling `.ToString()` on an object.

Change your method signature to this:

```
public IActionResult Get(int id)
```

and then simply:

```
return Ok(test);
```

**Note**: You can change the signature to return `WmsInformation`, but using action results lets you return error codes easily, too.

Comment: So simple, note to self never code after sleepless nights

Comment: @Matt idk, being a night owl I do some of my best coding late at night. There is a diminishing point of returns though :-D

Comment: Let me rephrase, never code after sleepless nights due to being severly intoxicated :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to use JsonResult instead of string

```
public JsonResult Get(int id)
    {
        var test = new WmsInformation();
        test.WmsInfos = new List<WmsInfo>
        {
            new WmsInfo { StoreName = "SE001", ItemName = "Item1" , ItemQty = "10"},
            new WmsInfo { StoreName = "SE002", ItemName = "Item2" , ItemQty = "115"}
        };

        return new JsonResult(test);
    }
```

I hope you find it useful

Comment: this doesn't work. What version of DotNet are you using?  JsonResult doesn't take any parameters (it's not  a method)

Answer (score -1):

That is valid JSON. It’s a string, just like your return type.

I imagine you’re trying to serialize the object, rather that use ToString, which will return the type name by default.

You could just return the object instead of using ToString, and adjust your method signature to account for the change.

This will start the content negotiation process and end up serializing your object to (probably) JSON.

```
public WmsInformation Get(int is)
{
    var test = new WmsInformation
    {
        WmsInfos = ...
    }

    return test;
}
```